# How to rectify a georeferenced Google Earth image and corresponding layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, google-earth, digital-image-processing

[image]I am still a newbie to georeferencing and ArcGIS.

I imported an image with place markers from Google Earth. Then I opened up the image in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1. I then georeferenced the control points and converted the KML file for my point data from Google Earth. This worked and all the data lines up perfectly. However, my image and the data are on an angle. How can I rotate everything so I can make a usable map?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "my image and the data are on an angle"? A screenshot of your problem would help. Are you looking to rotate the dataframe for cartographic purposes? If so, try right-clicking the dataframe in the table of contents > Properties... > General > Rotation.

Comment: If your data frame is in a different coordinate system than the one Google Earth uses, it is quite possible that the image would look "rotated".  If that is the case and you want a nice rectangular "unrotated" image, change your data frame to Google's system (WGS 84 Web Mercator): See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52209/coordinate-system-and-projection-for-georeferencing-google-maps-image-in-arcgis

Comment: Sorry. I am really new to online forums. How do I post a screenshot?

Comment: @Aaron. I tried rotating the data frame, but the problem is that I need to clip the image. When I clip the image using a polygon in the rotated data frame, the results are not good, to say the least.

Comment: @johns-I tried this and the results are the same. The image and data are still on an angle.

Comment: Thanks Chris. The problem tis that I was trying to upload a picture into a comment and this is not possible.

Comment: @Aaron. Thanks. Adjusting the rotation from the data frame properties and using Extract by mask worked. The border pixels look a little ragged, but I can live with that.